# React | How to check if the initial state is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, state

I'm working on a React application with multiple sections on a page. Each section will have a form that will be pre populated on form load.
Now let's say the user updates a value in the first section (say changes a textbox value), I want to mark that section as 'dirty' and when the submit button is clicked, that section state will also be passed onto the server.

This means if section A,,B and C got changed, I'd want to have a mechanism to Mark them dirty and only the sorry sections will be submitted.

Probably one way would be to keep a separate initial state object and compare it with current state but that would mean managing separate larger state values.
I was wondering if there's a cleaner way of doing this.

Comment: I've used the pattern you describe successfully. A simpler approach would be a single `dirty` var per section. This has the side effect of submitting even if the user reverted to the original state, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: Have you tried store.subscribe in redux? 
    @va1b4av

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for state in redux
You should use from store.subscribe in your componentDidMount.its a listener for redux.
Every time that your store in redux has changed store.subscribe will called.

```
...
//"You should give your store address"
import store from "yourStoreForRedux/store";


componentDidMount() {
    store.subscribe(() => {
       //Store.getState is a function for redux that give you 
       //,your store
      let data = store.getState();

      //In this place call every function that you want to call 
      //per every store changed for example I setState
       this.setState({ reduxProduct: data });
  }
```